# Объем шара на С

Tags: c, математика

только начал учить С и пока мало что понимаю попробовал сделать такой код но что то не выходит

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>



int main()
{
float r;
printf("Введіть  r: ");
scanf("%f", &r);
float 4*pi*r^3/3;
return 0;
}
```

почему то выдает такую ошибку при компиляции

```
./Root/main.c: In function 'main':
./Root/main.c:12:7: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
 float 4*pi*r^3/3;

       ^
```

П.С. лаба в универе по С а первый вводный урок будет после лабы...

Comment: А это ничего, что объем сферы по определению - 0? В отличие от объема шара? :) А по ошибке - ну так определите сначала переменную для объема, если хотите написать `float`. Если нет - просто выводите значение через `printf`. И учтите, что `^` - это побитовое исключающее или, а не возведение в степень...

Comment: pi неопределено, задайте pi как 3.14, либо берите из библиотеки, а не из текущего контекста как сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

списывай

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float r;
    printf("Введіть  r: ");
    scanf("%f", &r);
    float v = 4*M_PI*powf(r,3)/3;
    printf("V = %f",v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: о, а M_PI уже доступен просто так?

Comment: ну да в math.h определен, хз может конечно не у всех вендеров

Comment: оно определено, но в половине случаев скрыто за ifdef.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
float r;
printf("Введіть  r: ");
scanf("%f", &r);
```

хорошо бы проверять корректность ввода, что не введен какой-то текст к примеру
так же лучше проверять, не введён ли отрицательный радиус и выдавать соответствующие предупреждения и требовать повторный ввод

```
float 4*pi*r^3/3;
```

чему именно вы присваиваете это значение? `4*pi*r^3/3;`

`pi` - это название переменной, вы его не определили, надо делать или

```
const float pi = 3.14159;
```

или

```
4*3.14159*r^3/3;
```

или использовать значение из библиотеки

```
4*M_PI*r^3/3;
```

и где вывод полученного результата на экран перед выходом?

```
return 0;
}
```